# Android listadapter Anchor

Tags: android, listadapter

Lets say I have 1 - 1,000 in a list and I click on 250. When I push the back button I want to go back to 250 not all the way back up to 1.

Is this possible?

Comment: Ok I can use getSelectedItemPosition() but only if I scroll with the arrow keys, not on a click....

Comment: Figured it out. And It was easy. I just used the position int in the onclick listener then sent that data over in the extras and sent it back when someone hit the back button. Then I called setSelection(Int) and it works great.

Answer (score 0):

I have not tried this but you could try to save the state of the `ListActivity` before advancing to the next activity. In your list item selection handler you would store the selected index in a `Bundle` with `saveInstanceState()` and then advance to the next activity. When the activity is returned to ( user presses back button ) you can override `onRestoreInstanceState()` which will have the cached `Bundle` passed to it as a parameter. From there you could call `smoothScrollToPosition()` on the `ListView`, passing in the saved index.